# Google Calendar API Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use Google Calendar API with NodeJS, so I'm following the official tutorial: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs
I come to Step 4: Run the sample. 

When I start to run it: node quickstart.js

It says : `"No upcoming events found."`

 I don't get it. How do I have access to this calendar?

Comment: Try changing the calendarId from "primary" to the name of your actual google calendar

Answer (score 0):

Have you put any events in your calendar? Maybe it's actually empty. Since it seems to be reading everything fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try share your events to your service account? That worked for me btw...

Answer (score 0):

Open `Google calenders` and create events for future dates like anything like

```
Visit park on 10/11/2017 or 30/12/2017.
```

As you will do this and then again run the command `node quickstart.js` file ,you will see it will list all the upcoming events in the console.